# How to use a custom command line in place of terminal for VS Code?

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio-code, cmd, customization

I have a custom `cmd.exe` shortcut that I use with a modified target to a `shell.bat` that calls `vcvarsall.bat` so I can run `cl` from custom `build.bat` files for my projects.

I attempted to change the setting for the default terminal in `settings.json` **from:**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

**To:**

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Development\\CustomCP\\custom_shell_cmd.exe",
```

The `custom_shell_cmd.exe` runs and will compile code as it should and I have been using it for about a year with no issues.

Visual Studio Code returns with the following error when trying to open a terminal with the path:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Development\CustomCP\custom_cmd.exe" does not exist.
```

The setting for "intgrated" vs "external" under Terminal doesn't change the outcome. When set to external the error persists.

The custom target is:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k  "c:\Development\vcvarsallCLshell\shell_VS2019_CE.bat"
```

So the shortcut calls `cmd.exe` like normal, then runs my shell script. Works like a charm. Just won't work with VS Code Integrated Terminal.

Just in case, here is the shell script:

```
@echo off

rem shell.bat for VS2019 Community install

call "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

Comment: Check `custom_shell_cmd.exe` against `custom_cmd.exe` – is there a typo?

Comment: @aschipfl I have since changed the settings.json to the point of not having this code in there anymore, great catch though.  If I remember right I attempted to use just a default cmd.exe shortcut and had the same issue.  It doens't like shortcuts but I need it to be a shortcut to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but in a round about way.

Visual Studio Code does not accept my custom `cmd.exe` from inside the app but since VSCODE is on `PATH` as `code .` I can add `code .` to my batch file and open Visual Stuio Code in the command prompt instance running `vcvarsall.bat`.

The new file:

```
@echo off

rem shell.bat for VS2019 Community install

call "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

code .
```

This allows me to stay within the visual studio editor and use ***ctrl + (back-tick)*** to open and move to a `cmd.exe` that is now running `vcvarsall.bat`.

This allows me to compile without leaving VSCODE and that saves alot of time switching to the open `cmd.exe`

This also opens the possibility of a custom desktop/taskbar shortcut for vscode.  One click to open everything.

I have made the batch files available on github [here](https://github.com/T-Felm-Lee/vcvarsallCLshell).

There is also instruction on how to get this to work in the `readme.md`.